# how to integrate routing(found-relay) in relay without its typings?

Tags: routes, relayjs, relaymodern

i want to create a web app in relay using found-relay routing. I looked at this sample in relay modern which i think is great: [sample](https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-compiler-language-typescript/tree/master/example?fbclid=IwAR1TOmNsC4QRy5ejrHgajK3FWcPf3rAEjdbYzHRvb_IajV7NbMhxHZOTr1Q)  but i try tried to look at [found-relay](https://github.com/relay-tools/found-relay) and I can't find @types/found-relay unlike @types/react-router-dom? i am wondering if it'd be possible to use found-relay in relay modern+typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best practice, but I solved it like this:

create `types.d.ts` in your `./src` and add `declare module 'found-relay'`. That's it.

It works for me!